# React: Iterate over object, find array, and display array items

Tags: arrays, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to iterate over an object being return by the axios call to "/Home/NewsNotes".

Response from Axios
[image]

I'm able to display the property names to the screen, but I'm having issues accessing the "NewsNotes" array.

[image]

Here's my code for my component.

[image]

```
class ReleaseDetailsComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        releaseNotes: {}
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const currCatId = urlParams.get('categoryId');
    axios.get('/Home/NewsNotes?categoryId=' + currCatId)
        .then(response => _this.setState(
            { releaseNotes: response.data }
        ))
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    console.log(currCatId);
}

render() {
    return (
        <section>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <h2 className="page-title tutorials"><img className="title-icon" src="/Content/images/icons/icon-release-notes.png" /> News & Release Notes</h2>
                    <h3>{this.state.releaseNotes.Title}</h3>
                    {Object.keys(this.state.releaseNotes).map(function (item, key) {
                        return (
                            <p>{item}</p>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<ReleaseDetailsComponent />,
document.getElementById('tutorialsWrapper')
);
```

Comment: access it using ```this.state.releaseNotes.NewsNotes```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the object which you retrieved from URL using axios will look like:

```
var releaseNotes = {
    NewsNotes: [
        "Buy some milk": "data 1",
        "Clean kitchen": "data 2",
        "Watch Netflix": "data 3"
    ],
    NewsNotesCategoryId: 3,
    SortOrder: null,
    Title: "1.0.1",
    TypeId: 2
};
```

Next, you can inject "this" into map method as follow, check for any child array, then push each JSX block into the temp array in order to return later:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.releaseNotes).map((key, idx) => {
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(<p>{key}</p>);

    if (Array.isArray(this.state.releaseNotes[key])) {
        this.state.releaseNotes[key].map(ckey => {
            temp.push(<p>{ckey}</p>);
        });
    }

    return temp;
}, this)}
```

Comment: So it is just the matter of what you would like to get. For example, I would like to take Body for the list, then in the if statement: 
`this.state.releaseNotes[key].map((key, idx) => {
                              temp.push(<p>{key.Body}</p>);
                           });`

Answer (score 0):

You can't render an array of elements using keys. Rather map over the array and print them like this.

```
renderReleaseNotes() {
  return _.map(this.state.releaseNotes, releaseNote => {
    return (
      <p>releaseNote.title</p>

    );
  });
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !