# How to iterate over array of objects in ReactTable so as to display the data?

Tags: arrays, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, react-table

Reactjs:
I have been trying to build a ReactTable(npm ) from axios get request.The response data is in object of array format. So I can't populate my table .I am getting type-error : UN-handled Rejection (TypeError): resolvedData.map is not a function. I am aware the react table map cannot map over array of objects .I don't know how to map over and populate the table.

My axios.get request

```
    componentDidMount(){
        const url="http://localhost:5000/api/users/tenantView";
        fetch (url,{
            method: "GET"
        }).then(response=> response.json()).then(usersList=>{
           console.log((usersList)) ;
           this.setState({
            usersList : usersList
           });            
        })
  }
```

Here I am seeing the response in console,the data is being fetched correctly

```
{user: Array(5)}
user: Array(5)
0: {_id: "5d36f73f67665a1740620f55", name: "Pritam Kumar", email: "pritamchandra94@gmail.com", password: "$2a$10$ly84W9WLQr/Qih/AzN0PuOExctk5ohR9TxjtT.PUdsy4h6a9sY6pW", location: "Pune", …}
1: {_id: "5d36fc9c30ddd31638192498", name: "Raja", email: "raj@gmail.com", password: "$2a$10$KC5i6EkDb5SIqaMQPh.RoumQON6PEYZIDE4TM1oTH6xhmOTaD.FOy", location: "Durgapur", …}
2: {_id: "5d3ac84a86688123789e13b2", name: "Puja", email: "puja@gmail.com", password: "$2a$10$r17zOU1gTJvwoB.nBdRvi.qvDmsJhIlHbp//s8l0KEKgCEvbKoZAu", location: "Delhi", …}
3: {_id: "5d400d8f23eda427b0c020e0", name: "Goobi", email: "goobi@gmail.com", password: "$2a$10$sW/Cs32ouY2ZBPQ0sQK7YeRUNkdRfjucf/Y4ykiPbZRtXn49rm1rm", location: "Durgapur", …}
4: {_id: "5d492a271294110f64196b2c", name: "Imran", email: "imran@gmail.com", password: "$2a$10$V5KWD60GrV1eNuOkDtTHVu9SjA2k6gshmwzWieYzJpus3fwhPWnbu", location: "Durgapur", …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

I have tried to map over by similar to this link but its not working
[React: Iterate over object, find array, and display array items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036555/react-iterate-over-object-find-array-and-display-array-items)

I have also tried to map in accessor like in 
[react-table iterating over object array to print values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411869/react-table-iterating-over-object-array-to-print-values-in-a-column)

I may be incorrect. Please have a look.Will these work ?

Render function

```
render() {
        const columns =[
            {

                Header:"User ID",
                accessor:"_id",
                sortable: false,
                filterable: false,
                style:{
                    textAlign: "left"
                },
                width: 100,
                maxWidth: 100,
                minWidth: 100,
            },
            {
                Header:"Name ",
                accessor:"name",
                filterable: false,

            },
            {

                Header:"Email",
                accessor:"email"
            },
            {

                Header:"Password",
                accessor:"password"
            },
            {

                Header:"Farm",
                accessor:"farm"
            },

        ]
       return(
           <ReactTable
           columns={columns}
           data={this.state.usersList}
           defaultPageSize={20}
           >

           </ReactTable>

       );
    }
}
```

Populate the table: No data is populated now.

Comment: try `this.state.usersList.user` it looks like the data lives there.

Comment: ```this.userList.user``` is  not working @jsw324

Comment: Does React table is able to map over array of objects because the axios request is returning me with {user:Array(5)}

Answer (score 0):

You are passing object instead of array. Just pass the data like that:

```
<ReactTable
               columns={columns}
               data={this.state.usersList.user}
               defaultPageSize={20}
>
```

Comment: I have tried this but this seems not to work, the fields are still empty while in console I can see the o/p.

Answer (score 0):

1. *There are several things to remember while handling with React Table*.I *was working today on this code and found out that resolvedData.map function of React Table can iterate over arrays or [{}] but not {}*  
   **React Table cannot iterate over objects by default.**

   2. My backend main code where I found error ,
      the response was encapsulated with user object format , I
      changed it by removing  `{ }` ,then my response was in [{ }] where [ ] was missing

       **code**:

      `await User.find( ).lean(true).then(user => {return res.send(user);... //here`
   3. After that my code started working,the resolvedData.map function of React Table could display list of all users in my Database by without the use of
      `this.state.userList.user`. 
      If I bind the response in `res.send({user})`
      then also the default map function doesn't work on {}.My response was missing `[{data}]` rather it was returning `{[ ]}`

      Thank you all for helping.